# Adaptive Theme for Drupal : aggregating CSS disable responsive styles

Tags: drupal-7, aggregate, adaptive-design

I've got a problem with aggregating my css in Drupal 7. I work on Adaptive theme and I'm using responsive stylesheets on my website.
When I check "Aggregate CCS" in drupal administration, my website appears as desktop styles.
Is anybody has a issue ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, in this particular template you should save the template settings after css changes has been done.